# python xpath in xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xpath

I use `xml.etree.ElementTree` with the function `root.findall(xpath)`
How can I find all roots' children which have 'Status' child with text 'Pass'?

```
<Root>
    <Some_Element> <!-- I want only this element -->
        <Status>Pass</Status>
    </Some_Element>
    <Some_Element>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
    </Some_Element>
</Root>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
elements = [x for x in root.findall("Some_Element") if x.find("Status").text == "Pass"]
```